# Play Framework Json Serialization Failure

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have an implicit Json reads and writes as below:

```
  implicit val userJsonWrites = new Writes[User] {
    override def writes(user: User): JsValue = Json.obj(
      idKey -> Json.toJson(user._id),
      firstNameKey -> Json.toJson(user.firstName),
      lastNameKey -> Json.toJson(user.lastName),
      emailKey -> Json.toJson(user.email),
      //passKey -> Json.toJson(user.pass),
      addressKey -> Json.toJson(user.address),
      createDateKey  -> Json.toJson(user.createDate),
      activateDateKey  -> Json.toJson(user.activateDate),
      isUserActivatedKey -> Json.toJson(user.isUserActivated),
      verificationDateKey  -> Json.toJson(user.verificationDate)
    )
  }

  implicit val userJsonReads = new Reads[User] {
    override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[User] = {
      val user = User(
        _id = (json \ idKey).as[Option[String]],
        firstName =  (json \ firstNameKey).as[String],
        lastName =  (json \ lastNameKey).as[String],
        email =  (json \ emailKey).as[String],
        pass =  (json \ passKey).as[String],
        address = (json \ addressKey).as[Address],
        createDate =  (json \ createDateKey).as[DateTime],
        activateDate =  (json \ activateDateKey).as[Option[DateTime]],
        verificationDate =  (json \ verificationDateKey).as[Option[DateTime]],
        isUserActivated = (json \ isUserActivatedKey).as[Boolean]
      )

      JsSuccess(user)
    }
  }
```

When I compile, I get the following failures:

```
Error:(84, 32) not enough arguments for method as: (implicit fjs: play.api.libs.json.Reads[Option[String]])Option[String].
Unspecified value parameter fjs.
        _id = (json \ idKey).as[Option[String]],
                               ^
Error:(84, 32) No Json deserializer found for type Option[String]. Try to implement an implicit Reads or Format for this type.
        _id = (json \ idKey).as[Option[String]],
                           ^
```

My User object looks like this:

```
case class User(
  _id: Option[String],
  createDate: DateTime,
  activateDate: Option[DateTime],
  verificationDate: Option[DateTime],
  email: String,
  pass: String,
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  isUserActivated: Boolean,
  address: Address
)
```

The _id is actually the MongoDB's ObjectId which I had to have as an Option!

Comment: You should look into JSON combinators instead of trying to write reads/writes like that. That method is very brittle and unforgiving.

Comment: Could you please give me an example?

Comment: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonCombinators#Putting-it-all-together

Comment: I'm not satisfied with JSON combinators. It seems to be an overkill for a JSON conversion that I would like to keep in simple without much of Scala or Play framework crappy coolness!

Comment: try `asOpt[String]` instead of `as[Option[String]]`. You can probably eliminate all of this boilerplate using the `Json.format` macro.

Comment: Your 20 - 30 lines of code is far from simple. Not only that, but it will _*throw an exception*_ on the first error! Using combinators, you safely aggregate all validation errors.

Comment: Ok that aggregation of all validation errors is a valid argument as to why I should use combinators!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `asOpt`, see [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/tr/2.4.x/ScalaJson)

It should look like;

```
...
_id = (json \ idKey).asOpt[String]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should almost always prefer the provided macro implementations of Reads/Writes/Format over writing your own logic:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

implicit val userJsonWrites = Json.writes[User]
implicit val userJsonReads = Json.reads[User]
```

Comment: Can you explain more "you should almost always prefer "